# How to revert function definitions in Vim?

Tags: function, vim, neovim

I don't know how to revert my function. Say I have this in `.vimrc`:

```
function! TempFunc()
  " Temporary stuff
  nnoremap v <c-v>

  ...

endfunction

silent! call TempFunc()
```

It'll call `TempFunc()`, right. I guess this function (and what inside it) will be deleted if I run command:

```
:delfunction! TempFunc
```

It deleting the `TempFunc()` but not including what its returned. So here `v` is still bound to `<c-v>`.

What I want is, if I delete `TempFunc()`, the code inside it will get deleted too and I lost my Temporary stuff. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

When you called `TempFunc()` it executed `nnoremap v <c-v>`. The mapping doesn't remember it came from the function so removing the function doesn't revert the mapping.

There is no single universal way to undo what a function have done — for every line in the function you must find its own way to undo.

In you case you need to unmap the mapping:

```
unmap v
```

Comment: What if I groupping my temporary stuff in `augroup` block. Is it still behave the same?

Comment: Changes in the environment created by a function are not tied to the function. You can undo a group but you have to undo it manually, deleting the function doesn't undo changes it produced.